# Select not equal values while grouping

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Each document describes customer agrement (decision, not value), Simplified:

```
{
    "_id": "123",
    "customerID" : "Smith"
    "agreement": [
        {"agreementType":"A"
        "agreementValue":"T"},
        {"agreementType":"B"
        "agreementValue":"T"}]
}
{
    "_id": "124",
    "customerID" : "Smith"
    "agreement": [
        {"agreementType":"A"
        "agreementValue":"F"},
        {"agreementType":"B"
        "agreementValue":"T"}]
}
{
    "_id": "125",
    "customerID" : "Brown"
    "agreement": [
        {"agreementType":"A"
        "agreementValue":"T"},
        {"agreementType":"B"
        "agreementValue":"T"}]
}
{
    "_id": "126",
    "customerID" : "Brown"
    "agreement": [
        {"agreementType":"A"
        "agreementValue":"T"},
        {"agreementType":"B"
        "agreementValue":"T"}]
}
```

I need to query all customers that have different agreementValues for same agreementType (ex. single customer agreed and next day disagreed).
It should return Smith (different values for agreementType=A).

currently I can find all duplicates, but cannot limit to those with different values

Answer (score 0):

You can `$unwind` the `agreement` array and perform `$group` to get the distinct values of `agreementValue`. `$match` with `$size` greater than 1 to get desired records.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$unwind": "$agreement"
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": {
        "customerID": "$customerID",
        "agreementType": "$agreement.agreementType"
      },
      "agreementValues": {
        "$addToSet": "$agreement.agreementValue"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      $expr: {
        $gt: [
          {
            $size: "$agreementValues"
          },
          1
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id.customerID"
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/0Ow_DDhKbh8)